# RollingFileAppender not clearing log file in log4j2 version 2.5

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender

We are using log4j2 on Window 7 Enterprise.
JBoss Developer Studio 8(this really doesn't matter)

RollingFileAppender rolls over the log files properly, however the original log file keep old logs and continues to increase in size. There is a JIRA bug (LOG4J2-904) related to this . I followed some of the options like

- fileIndex="min" or fileIndex="max"

  Using RollingRandomAccessFile instead of RollingFile.

Some comments indicated problem fixed as of log4j 2.4.1 version. However, I am still seeing the same problem in log4j 2.5.

I tried logging to both RollingFile and RollingRandomAccessFile appenders at the same time. An image of the log folder in included [Here is the image of Log folder from rollover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/264iV.png)

Here is my log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration>
<Properties>
    <property name="appname">myapp</property>
    <Property name="log-path">${server.dir}/myapp</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="DATED_ROLLING_FILE" fileName="${log-path}/${myapp}.log" filePattern="${log-path}/${myapp}_%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" maxFileSize="40 KB">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d: %-5p [%c{1}]:%L - %M %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="40 KB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="min" max="100" />
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="DATED_RAC_APPENDER" fileName="${log-path}/epermitsrac.log"
    filePattern="${log-path}/epermitsrac_%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d: %-5p [%c{1}]:%L - %M %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="40 KB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="min" max="100" />
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="DATED_ROLLING_FILE" />
        <AppenderRef ref="DATED_RAC_APPENDER" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

[Here is the image of Log folder from rollover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/264iV.png). As you can see it does not clear the original File.

Did anyone else experienced same problem and is there a fix for this.

Comment: Can you replace the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with the CronTriggeringPolicy and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Do you have multiple processes or web apps with the same config (writing to the same file)?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @RemkoPopma, we do NOThave multiple web apps writing to same file. Sorry for late response.

Comment: @rgoers I have not tried CronTriggeringPolicy yet. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with below configuration and it is working fine, except that the latest file will be with out date.

## the log4j2.properties configuration

```html
rootLogger.level = all
appenders = rolling, console

status = warn

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d [%-5p] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

# Rolling file based on date for day wise
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling

#if i use below file name the rollover will not happenning as expected
#appender.rolling.fileName = E:/LOGS/${date:yyyyMMdd}_test.log 

#with below filename name the rollover will happen as expected 
appender.rolling.fileName = E:/LOGS/test.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = E:/LOGS/%d{yyyyMMdd}_test.log

appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d [%-5p] [%F:%M:%L] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

#use below for day wise roll over 
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
 
rootLogger.appenderRefs = rolling, console

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = console
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = rolling

rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = console, rolling
```

Comment: this will generate the files as below:
test.log               (latest log) 
20220325_test.log
20220324_test.log
20220323_test.log